# PHP keep and pass $_GET in a nginx rewrite

Tags: php, nginx

I'm using this rewrite:

```
location = /example-page {
    try_files $uri /pages/example-page.php;
}
```

This rewrite is causing `$_GET` not to be available for some reason.

When I go to `example-page.php?test` and use `print_r($_GET);` it returns an empty Array. If however I access the file directly, as in `/pages/example-page.php?test`

I get `Array ( [test] => )`

My question is, how can I make it so that all these vars, like `$_GET` are kept, using the rewrite?

Comment: Your `try_files` statement is stripping off the argument. You could try: `try_files $uri /pages/example-page.php$is_args$args;`

Comment: Hm, I kinda wanted to make a question that also answers, which kind of rewrites would cause $_GET not to be available anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corrected rewrite as mentioned in comment, while will work, is the least preferred:

```
location = /example-page {
    try_files $uri /pages/example-page.php$is_args$args;
}
```

It is sub-optimal, because it checks existence of file `<webroot>/example-page` for *every* request to `/example-page` URI. Sure enough, this file does not exist to begin with. So all the file existence checks are in vain. That, depending on traffic and disk used, will be a reason for performance issues.

[Getting rid](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too) of `try_files` to reduce `stat` system calls is preferable in this case. Simply tell NGINX to route request via PHP-FPM, as well as which filename the PHP-FPM has to use for processing:

```
location = /example-page {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/pages/example-page.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock;
}
```